Raydium Swap InvalidInstructionData
I am getting InvalidInstructionData error when trying to execute a raydium SwapBaseIn Instruction. I am using GoLang to construct the swap transaction. I am getting all the parameters from an other swap instruction since I am working on a copytrader.
Here is an example of a transaction I am copying: Solscan 2nmT..

Since all account arguments are equal except the last three, being:

User Source Token Account
User Destination Token Account
User Source owner.

I copy all the other accounts and change the last 3. Resulting in this transaction (this is mine)

However when executing this I get "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: invalid instruction data" in the logs.
Any pointers on where to continue, I have no idea what is wrong with this. The Associated Token Accounts are created for both WSOL and the token mint in the same transaction, in the instructions before it. Here is the layout of the transaction:

Compute Budget
Create ATA for WSOL
Transfer Lamports (amount of sol to buy)
SyncNative instruction
Create ATA for token mint
Swap IX
Close WSOL ATA

Edit:
I tried using the Raydium TS SDK V2, and was able to get it working with the exact same account arguments:

Therefore my issue was not with invalid arguments, but most likely with creating the WSOl account, here is the successfull tx : solscan
Why is there a ata create for wsol (call it a), then a create with seed again for wsol(b), just to transfer the wsol from b to a, rather than transferring from main wallet + sync to a?
Edit 2:
Here is my failed transaction onchain vs the successful one:
mine vs success
On solana.fm the instruction is unkown : link

Turns out the reason it was failing,was because of the instruction identifier being wrong.
I generated the raydium idk through anchor-go, which supposedly generated incorrect code. Tried building it manually and it worked.
